# Related Questions/Linked Questions on Stack Exchange beta sites not appearing as links when hovered

Tags: bug, user-interface, design, related-questions, beta-phase

As I couldn't find anything related to this specific point under the tags [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) + [related-questions](/questions/tagged/related-questions) + [beta](/questions/tagged/beta), I'm raising here the question.

Happens that when hovering the related/linked questions on any beta site, the links aren't appearing as proper links.

This 'behaviour' (as I'm not sure if that's a bug or not) has been noticed by a pmse user who raised this meta post: [Related links not obvious as links](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/433/430).

I asked some mods and, as MadScientist noticed, beta links are missing the `.question-hyperlink:hover` css entry.

The question here is: **is this an expected behaviour or a bug?**

Comment: The hovering works on the per-site metas, which is a strong indicator for me that this is a bug and not intentional.

Comment: That's a good point, @MadScientist.

Comment: I can see why one might be blind to it, if indeed it's unintentional .. I didn't notice it until you pointed it out.